# How to remove elements from listview JQUERY mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

There is a list view and this is loaded dynamically upon loading the page.
    This adds elements inside list view.
    The problem is i have placed backbutton.After going to previous screen and returning back to current screen it is loading the data and appending to the List View.

```
I need to remove the <li> elements from the list view.

The HTML code snippet.
<ul id="mymenu" data-role="listview" >
</ul>

Jquery Code Snippet.
$("#mypmenu").append('<li><a href='+ "#" + ' id="a"  "> <img src="letterheader.png" >'+ this.textContent + '  </a> </li>'); 


Now i need to remove the elements from the list view (mymenu)which are loaded already.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try emptying your list before appending list items first. Afterwards, make sure to call the refresh function of the listview widget, so jQuery Mobile will be rendering your list correctly.

```
$("#mypmenu").empty().append('<li><a href='+ "#" + ' id="a"  "> <img src="letterheader.png" >'+ this.textContent + '  </a> </li>').listview("refresh");
```

See also http://forum.jquery.com/topic/dynamically-generated-listview

Answer (score 0):

`$("mypmenu").empty(), followed by $("mypmenu").append()`

does the job for me

Answer (score 0):

this work for me

```
$("mypmenu li").remove();
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't use append then.     
use

```
$("#mypmenu").html('<li><a href='+ "#" + ' id="a"  "> <img src="letterheader.png" >'+ this.textContent + '  </a> </li>').listview("refresh");
```

Answer (score -1):

Write your code in "pagecreate", this runs the code just one time.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#pageone", function () {}
```

[page create](https://www.quanzhanketang.com/jquerymobile/event_pagecreate.html)