# Remove item from jquery mobile listview?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to remove an item from a jquery mobile listview without having to repopulate the whole listview?

Answer (score 4):

using jQuery....

```
$('#id').remove();
```

i think **[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249345/removing-specific-element-from-a-list-with-jquery)** can help you..

also, **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727272/how-to-remove-elements-from-listview-jquery-mobile)** for jQuery mobile.

**[Here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-beta.1/docs/demos/swipe/swipe-list.html#)** is the demo for jQuery mobile...